Proposal to change the protocol for closing questions
In some cases questions may be deemed off-topic or there may be other good reasons for closing a question. The current protocol for this is that 5 community members, with some minimum status points, should vote to close.
This protocol as such does not seem unreasonable to me. However, I believe it does become unreasonable when at least two (or more) other users have already written answers to the OPs question.
I believe when that is the case it shows that at least those users did not find the question off-topic (or otherwise unsuitable) for this SE. In other words, it shows that the meta-question, whether or not the OPs question is unsuitable, is contentious in the eyes of community members. (Only in very rare cases, I assume, would someone take time to answer the OPs question, and then still vote, afterwards, to close it. I don't quite understand why someone would ever do so. I'd be tempted to see this as an irrational, or perhaps even disingenuous (?) action since the main, intended effect -- if enough close votes are aggregated -- is to block other users from engaging with the question and trying to answer it.)
When other community members have taken time to answer a question, it also seems rather disrespectful to them to then still close a question. In my eyes this does not create a welcoming atmosphere in which we try to maintain mutual respect and try to foster civil discourse (which I see as core values on a forum like this).
Given the above two points, I propose to change the protocol of closing questions a little. As follows

For any posted question, if at least two other people (other than the OP of the question) have written answers (not just comments, but actual answer posts), it should (in principle) be impossible to close the question. Close votes can then still be registered, but they will automatically remain ineffective.

Please note that I'm adding the caveat "in principle" to allow for action against (for example) teams (or apparent teams) of trolls (troll kabals). So, it should be possible that the site moderator overrides the protocol in an exceptional case where a troll posts a question and simultaneously posts two answers (using other accounts) or asks their buddies to do so. (I've seen at least two cases of pretty nasty trolling, similar to this, by a user who seemed to have multiple accounts, so it's good to be prepared against that.) In my proposal it would require the attention of the moderator(s), and only the moderator(s) should in this case have override rights.
Note also that in the exceptional cases when an answerer deletes their own answer, or when a moderator deletes one or more answers, any registered close votes could again become effective, which then could lead to closing the question (as now). This is why it still makes sense to always keep registering close votes.
In my proposal I'm a little arbitrarily asking for "at least two other people". Personally, I would find one answer post enough, but it seems more reasonable to ask for at least two in order to sufficiently demonstrate that the meta-question is contentious. You might ask, why not 5 (since 5 close votes are currently required)? I would find it reasonable to match the numbers if all close votes were also required to justify and argue for their preference. But since this is not the case, I think some measure of asymmetry is reasonable. In other words, I would also be for my proposal if it asked for at least 3 answers, but asking for more doesn't seem to make sense to me.
I'm not sure how the current protocol is established -- who or what imposes it. If this is a protocol that is established by the community itself, then this is my change proposal, which I put up for discussion.
If the community has no power to change the protocol, then I'd like to just suggest this change to who- or whatever is in charge of this.

I often feel the same way, that closure happens rather quickly and often. On the other hand, I have seen highly upvoted posts with 5 or a dozen or 2 dozen very upvoted answers get closed, even years after being asked, so I take it as: "you got someone's attention" and that's all. It really makes no sense. My modest proposal is for the first five people to view a post simply VTC and then only the good questions will get reopened. There are many ways to do things, some of them useful...

@ScottRowe There is an interesting principle in the Talmud: If a man is being tried for capital crime by a bench of 12 judges, and all 12 convict him, then he is to be freed because it proves not that he is guilty but that the evidence collection makes that slant inevitable. Also reminds me of George Carlin: "Bipartisan" agreement usually means that a larger-than-usual deception is being carried out.

Is this even something within site moderation powers? I assume that vote-to-close is more or less inbuilt into the SE formula

Very short answer to offer one possible view:
I think this is a bad idea. Especially when a question is vague or invites opinion there will be two answers fast, mostly by some random people who offer nothing but their own personal view on the matter which has nothing to do with expert answers. This could just as well be achieved by asking Johnjoe infront of the next best supermarket. And even if we said "upvoted answers", opinions tend to attract votes by equally opinionated fellow humans, especially if "popular" with a given populace.
I really think the quality of contributions here is bad enough as-is (on average) and changing the voting mechanism in that direction will only add to the noise in which useful and well-written and founded posts disappear.
Also, a closed question is not the end of the world. Address criticisms, edit the question, and if done right, there will fast be just as many votes to reopen.

Ok - I guess this really clinches it: "I really think the quality of contributions here is bad enough as-is (on average)"... :)

@mudskipper wait... Are you agreeing with the quoted sentence, or disagreeing? I agreed so upvoted the comment, then I thought, what did he mean about "this clinches it"?

I am unfortunately agreeing with that statement... :/ And given that -- my own proposal does seem to lose a lot of its attractiveness to me... That's why I accepted the whole answer. Also, I do agree that it's not such a big deal - at least not to me. The rather arbitrary and really inconsistent closing of questions also makes the site less attractive, but it doesn't happen too often I guess...

@ScottRowe - My overall problem - not directly related to this - is that the SE concept of Q&A as originally developed for software/coding (where it makes a lot of sense) doesn't make sense for this site. Anything apart from pure reference requests is problematic then. Because everything is/should be problematic in philosophy...

Btw, given the general poor quality of questions (and sometimes also of answers), it could also be argued -- paradoxically -- that posts should never be closed (apart from obvious trolling). There is usually some valid question behind any post -- so instead of lazily closing the posts, stimulate (and perhaps reward) editing posts...

So from your ✓  I take it you (@mudskipper)  are no  more interested in discussing alternatives to the status quo??

No, I'm still interested in hearing what people think of this and I am not at all satisfied about these kind of protocols - in the fact about the whole way the site is designed -, but it's just not such a big deal for me... In fact, I think this site is not really tenable/viable as is - the current overal SE design here (with the PSE specific rules) seems internally inconsistent/leading to unnecessary conflict. I will probably totally disengage in the near future...

I think there is real value in taking a comprehensive analysis of the issues. What is happening out here is at best piecemeal. But chat+ comments + VTCs + up-down-votes + flags interlock in multiple unexpected ways.

@Rushi There is nothing unexpected about this. The community has always been too lenient and so we ended up with more people thinking it's ok to write random thoughts, voting them up, and being able to "moderate" after some time because they themselves got enough (mostly undeserved IMHO) upvotes. This is a homemade problem with few people resisting the problematic trend. There is so much interesting stuff with real value for people interested in philosophy one could ask and answer within much stricter boundaries. Instead, we end up with opinions or random bits of "could be relevant".

A sort of "tragedy of the commons" thing, I suppose. We allowed overbrowsing.

I regularly vote to close then write an answer. To me that is not a contradiction.
Writing an answer is just a social interaction, it does not imply a question is a good fit for this site.
The goal of this site is not ta have a vibrant social network with lots of activities, the goal is to create a minimal knowledge base about philosophy.

+1 While I don't regard this as optimal behavior it's better than the power game that's the default. What I'd prefer (1) comment why unsuitable (1a) edit question if feasible/appropriate (2) answer elaborating comment/edit (3) Downvote with stronger comment (4) VTC. At each stage giving the questioner the opportunity to change

As to "not a social network" here is the message from stackexchange CEO: We are enthusiastic about welcoming this next generation of developers and technologists, providing them with a community and with solutions... Note the order of community and solutions

I feel like downvoting questions almost never is useful, there are too many here voting up just because there is any question at all.

A CEO Blogpost is not relevant to me. That just marketing.

It's marketing — obviously. "Just" marketing???? What does that mean? Are you claiming that a CEO of a million user site has no say in the direction taken by the site? Frankly I can't make out what you're saying however I squint

As to votes, yeah, SE rep is a hyperinflationary currency in that millions of users are "minting" 10 points out of thin air every time they vote up

I am saying "actions are louder than words". The whole site structure, with it's mechanisms and restrictions is more relevant than a CEO message.

The whole site includes you and I (and a couple of million more) who are currently in an animate discussion. Because we've been sufficiently well-gamed into believing that these are substantive discussions

I hate this conversation, it's a waste of my time, I don't feel becoming closer to you, and that's all right because I am not here for that. You want more friends, go on Facebook, Instagram, whatever social network.

You are free to "hate" this conversation — your prerogative.  You are also free to impute on a user (me) the gaming setup by the system. All this is irrelevant to this question and discussion  on VTCs. I would like to end this conversation by underscoring this comment thread as an unambiguous statement from you that downvoting is never useful whereas VTC is. I find this a misuse of the system; you're free to defend it as "kosher". Let the community decide

If the goal is to create a min. knowledge base about the history of philosophy, then the rules and protocols that are in place don't seem to be working very well. As to such knowledge bases, sites like SEP or IEP plus Wikipedia already provide that, so I don't see much reason to also keep this site around. The real background goal behind the site (the goal of SE) imo is to use whatever data users provide as data for OpenAI/overflow AI. I'm starting to think that that's about all there is to it...

As data for LLM training the content of most everything on PSA seems very uneven, so I would not even try to use it directly (again, other sites like SEP or even Wikipedia provide high quality data for this; using PSE would just require too much filtering/sifting). The main interest is probably in meta-data correlations (e.g. tags - number of answers - what type of questions come up most frequently - high freq. users). Those meta-data are easy to process and provide much more "substantial" info. Close votes and up/down votes are part of the meta-data.

@Rushi I was specifically talking about votes on questions (in non-meta). In meta it's super useful as a poll in suggestions, but in the non-meta sites it serves no purpose. Whereas for answer, voting impacts order and relevance, on questions it impacts nothing.

@mudskipper what you are saying sounds like the "you are the product" idea, especially when seen by AI.

I usually set the viewing order to see most recent answers first, otherwise I just see the ones other people voted up. Most recent seems much more useful than the default order. But about an answer being a social interaction when social interaction is not your purpose here or the purpose of the site, I don't understand. Votes on questions are a clue about what other people consider useful or interesting, so it matters. Again, I view recent activity, not vote sort order. Why go where everyone has gone before?

What other People found interesting at a very low voting activity reveals more about the other people than about the question. It's like, "oh we have a lot of people interested in politics today in the room". It does not mean that question is any more interesting than any other on one politics. Also all stackexchange sites are typically meant to be reached from search engines, not the start page. Only on stackoverflow is there such intense traffic and breadth that answerers need to filter, and some few would filter by question votes.

@ScottRowe - Indeed.

Ok. For me this SE is more like a 'water cooler' area where people bump in to each other and talk rather than a reference site. I don't have any burning need for answers to Philosophy questions, or really, many questions to ask other than: "why do people get so worked up about Philosophy and religion?" After the Buddha came along, it seems like it should have mostly disappeared.

The fact is classical discussion forums are mich better suited to create "water cooler" areas.
